# Why does (y < 10) imply everywhere (x > 0 ^ y < 10)?

Tags: logic, hoare-logic, software-verification

My lecturer recently released solutions to an assignment. One of the questions was to determine the weakest precondition of:

```
{y < 10} if (x > 0 OR y < 10) -> y:=10 fi {true}
```

According to the provided solution, the weakest precondition of the selection command

```
(x > 0 OR y < 10) -> y:=10
```

is

```
(x > 0 OR y < 10)
```

I understand how the weakest predicate was arrived at, but why does the solution then state that the total assertion is **true** because

```
 (y < 10) IMPLIES EVERYWHERE (x > 0 OR y < 10)
```

Isn't y < 10 **weaker than** (x > 0 OR y < 10)? Therefore, there are potential precondition states where y < 10 but x !> 0. Since the program doesn't have guards for such a condition, it then *aborts*.

Comment: " v " stands for or, the upside down " v " stands for and. So your title is wrong, inside the question it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.

Of course (y < 10) implies (x > 0 OR y < 10). I was somehow mistaking OR for AND. I'm dumb.

Comment: You're not dumb, you just need to learn to sit on your hands for 5 minutes before you post to stackexchange.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, story of my life